# iOS app search ads keyword tool says "You have no more recommended keywords for this app"

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect, search

We use the keyword popularity indicator under Advanced campaign editor at http://app.searchads.apple.com (described [here](https://appmasters.com/using-search-ads-find-keywords/)) to determine the popularity for keywords in the App Store.

However, as of today, when we enter a keyword, it says: "You have no more recommended keywords for this app" as shown in the screenshot.

What does this exactly mean? Is there some rate limiting on using keyword recommendations? If so, what are the limitations?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the documentation?

Comment: yes, neither the [campaign](https://searchads.apple.com/advanced/help/overview/#campaign-issues) or [keyword](https://searchads.apple.com/advanced/help/tools/#keywords) sections in the search ads advanced docs have any information on this error